# Is it possible to hide the hovered image and show another image using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

My problem is that I have 2 images; `#two` is initially hidden.

Is there any way in only CSS (no JS) so that when I hover at `#one` it gets hidden and `#two` is shown, possible with some animation

```css
#two{
    display:none;
}
#one:hover + #two{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<img id='one' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSoMUKwCL1uINRV035jkpfQzAbiObKqraXA6369mZBe0To0UuWP'>

<img id='two' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMYIpY4d8KlTzhAd38KZW8DIadeEV59WtLlxeIH3PS4uPXL0RP'>
```

PS: I am working on a Google Chrome Extension

EDIT: there is idea to use `background-image : url()` of image and change it on hover, but I don't want it, as it doesn't work, it needs to give full chrome extension path including extension ID

Comment: You can use something to over lay one image on another like 

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
}
#one{
  z-index: 1;
}
#two{
  z-index: 3;
}

Comment: @Ganeshchaitanya can u show me example

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you would use a wrapper div. You can then say that if you hover the wrapping div, you hide the first and show the second image. Are you able to use CSS only, or are you able to alter the HTML and you only want to prevent using JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ATomCalledStu has given the CSS only answer, but that only works if you have a relative wrapper.

What would work even better with any wrapper, is setting the `:hover` on the wrapper:

```css
.wrapper, img {
  display:inline-block;
}
#two {
  display:none;
}
.wrapper:hover #two {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper:hover #one {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img id='one' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSoMUKwCL1uINRV035jkpfQzAbiObKqraXA6369mZBe0To0UuWP'>

  <img id='two' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMYIpY4d8KlTzhAd38KZW8DIadeEV59WtLlxeIH3PS4uPXL0RP'>
</div>
```

If you alter somebody's website, you can probably see that the images most likely have a wrapper element (div, span, anything) and use that to set the `:hover` selector.

*I usually want to avoid `position:absolute` unless I am absolutely sure that the behavior never relies on relative positioning. In this case, especially because I don't know what your page looks like, the chances that `absolute` does not work seems very likely.*

**Update:**

If you want an animation, you are probably best off with `position:absolute` as the previous answer suggested. Sorry for the confusion ;)

Comment: I agree this is the better way to do it if you can alter the markup. though i would change to `inline-block` display to avoid the hover property firing on hover outside the image, like so: https://jsfiddle.net/cf80j75s/1/

Comment: @ATomCalledStu Good catch! Never saw that. I'll update the answer. Thx <3

Comment: @Randy I found this on the internet it looks like yours but it's a bit different [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u13fpkan/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can just overlay them with absolute positioning, then turn down the opacity on the top image on hover, like so:

```
img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition:all .6s ease;
}
#one {
  z-index:20;
}
#one:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/pksjg76x/

You can't use `display:none` in this case because you need the top element to remain inside the document to utilize the hover property. An opacity change might be your best option here, as long as you don't need the second image to contain any functionality besides viewing.

You can also use animation properties here very easily here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the complete solution, with animation:

You set them both as `position: absolute` and `body` is `position: relative` (or whatever container you have).

Then you set `display: block;` but `opacity: 0;` on the hidden one. set transitions on css on the hidden element and also set the same `opacity: 1;` when hovering the second element. You're good to go:

```css
#two {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

#one {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

#one:hover+#two,
#two:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img id='one' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSoMUKwCL1uINRV035jkpfQzAbiObKqraXA6369mZBe0To0UuWP'>

<img id='two' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMYIpY4d8KlTzhAd38KZW8DIadeEV59WtLlxeIH3PS4uPXL0RP'>
```

Comment: @ATomCalledStu Didn't notice as I was writing this. So, you can add a transition and I can delete mine.